# Finding the most frequently used tag for a day

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, schema

I need some guidance on how I would go about finding the most frequently used tag on a particular day.
This is the schema I am working with:

```
users(uid, name, city, crdate)
badges(bname, type)
ubadges(uid, bdate, bname)
posts(pid, pdate, title, body, poster(uid))
tags (pid, tag)
votes(pid, vno, vdate, uid)
questions(pid, theaid)
answers(pid, qid)
```

My best guess so far is the following query:

```
SELECT p.pdate,t.tag,COUNT(t.tag),MAX(t.tag) 
FROM posts p,tags t 
WHERE p.pid = t.pid 
GROUP BY p.pdate,t.tag;
```

Which returns the following:

```
2020-09-23|home|1|home
2020-09-23|work|1|work
2020-09-24|cake|2|cake
2020-09-24|pie|2|pie
2020-09-25|cake|1|cake
2020-09-25|pie|1|pie
2020-09-26|best|1|best
2020-09-26|unknown|1|unknown
2020-09-26|websites|1|websites
2020-09-27|archeology|1|archeology
2020-09-27|career|1|career
2020-09-27|chef|1|chef
2020-09-27|cooking|1|cooking
2020-09-27|free|1|free
2020-09-27|games|2|games
2020-09-27|job|1|job
2020-09-27|learning|1|learning
2020-09-27|media|1|media
2020-09-27|regex|1|regex
2020-09-27|sandbox|1|sandbox
2020-09-27|similar|1|similar
2020-09-27|smell|1|smell
2020-09-27|stress|1|stress
2020-09-27|ungratifying|1|ungratifying
2020-09-27|zooology|1|zooology
2020-09-28|cooking|1|cooking
2020-09-28|database|1|database
2020-09-28|eggs|7|eggs
```

For each date, it returns the tags used in posts and their count.
How would I go about displaying the tag with the highest count for each date?
My friend suggested something like this:

```
SELECT p.pdate,t.tag,COUNT(t.tag),MAX(t.tag) as max_tag 
FROM posts p,tags t 
WHERE p.pid = t.pid 
AND t.tag = max_tag 
GROUP BY p.pdate,t.tag;
```

But that gives me the following: Error: misuse of aggregate: MAX();

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Avoid of using joins this way: `FROM posts p,tags t WHERE p.pid = t.pid `, use proper join: `FROM posts p INNER JOIN tags t ON p.pid = t.pid`.

Comment: Please, what is your database provider: mysql or sqlite? This might be important!

Comment: I am using SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

With `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pdate, 
       FIRST_VALUE(t.tag) OVER (PARTITION BY p.pdate ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) tag,
       MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY p.pdate) counter
FROM posts p INNER JOIN tags t 
ON p.pid = t.pid 
GROUP BY p.pdate, t.tag;
```